# How to pass Map as a parameter from one .tsx file to another .tsx file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have declared a map in my Main file.
I have another file Test,to which i want to pass my map.Below is my Main.tsx file

```
const [testMap] = useState(new Map<string,PersonInfo|undefined>());
<Test list={testMap}/> //This is my Main.tsx file
```

Below is code for my Test.tsx file

```
interface Temp {
list:Map<string,PersonInfo|undefined>;
}
export default (
{list}:Temp
) => {
return (
<>
<p>
//Here i want to display the size of my map
</p>
</>
);
};
```

I want to display the size of the map that i have passed as parameter,but i am unable to do so.How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
interface Temp {
    list:Map<string,PersonInfo|undefined>;
}

export default ({list}:Temp) => {
    return (
        <p>
        //Here i want to display the size of my map
        {list.size()}
        </p>
    );
};
```

Also, if you want to use fragments, which is not necessary here, you have to make sure that the parent who calls your Test.jsx component displays it in a html element like a div.

```
<div>
    <Test list={testMap}/> //This is my Main.tsx file
</div>
```